# Override OpenAPI Generator BasePath on Generation

Tags: typescript, openapi-generator

I am creating a TypeScript Axios REST API client with [OpenAPI Generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/). I'm doing this in my terminal using `npx @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate -i ../swagger.json -g typescript-axios -o ./rest/`.

Since my host is depending on my .env variables, I want to read my API_URL from my env variables and pass it to the generating process of the generator.

I found [in the docs](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/typescript-axios#client-modification-feature) that changing the BasePath is in some way possible, but I can't figure out the way to do it. Adding `--basePath=1.2.3.4:8080` does not work, and I don't understand what "Defined by ToolingExtension" means.

Comment: i'm stuck exaclty at same situation as you, did you found any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing clean. As Robert says, localhost seems to be hardcoded within the tool. But you could write a bash script, that triggers the api generator and afterwards overrides the host in the resulting code by string replacement. It's not beautiful, but it works.

Comment: For those who are stuck on this, I ended up switching to openapi-typescript following this tutorial: 
https://blog.logrocket.com/generating-integrating-openapi-services-react/

Now I can set baseUrl, headers and more easily.

Answer (score 2):

In the latest `openapi-generator-cli 5.4.0` the `typescript-axios` generator respects the `servers` setting and uses the first [server object](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.1.0.md#server-object) in the list as the basePath - i.e. if you specify

```
{
   "openapi": "3.0.2",
   "info": { ... },
   "paths": { ... },
   "components": { ... },
   "servers": [ { "url" : "https://testurl.com" } ]
}
```

then the generated `base.ts` file should contain

```
export const BASE_PATH = "https://testurl.com".replace(/\/+$/, "");
```

Comment: You can also pass in `--server-variables` to specify different variables to use in the server object. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72182063/2892375

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that's arriving here from search, I've been able to set the `basePath` variable during generation. This was for the Angular generator but I think the outcome would be the same for the Axios generator. I set this variable by using `basePath=<YOUR_PATH>` in the `additional-properties` flag in the CLI `generate` command. An example would be:

```bash
npx --yes @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli \
    generate -i ./src/openapi.yaml \
    -g typescript-angular \
    -o ./src/generated-client \
    --additional-properties=fileNaming=kebab-case,basePath=''
```

You'll now see in your Angular classes the following:

```js
    protected basePath = '';
```

Comment: it works with `-g typescript-angular` but `-g typescript-axios` ignores it :(

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the "localhost" is hardcoded and as far as I can tell (after digging into the source code for the OpenAPI Generator) there is no way to change it. The documentation that mentions it is, I believe, referring to to the fact that the client that gets outputted allows that value to be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure is this relevant, but I've had the same issue today and I wasn't able to override it in any way I found online. I tried passing basePath as addition to the rest of additional paramas, but didn't worked.

Command I used in the end:

```
openapi-generator-cli generate -g typescript-axios -i https://api.mysite.com/swagger/v1/swagger.json --skip-validate-spec --additional-properties=useSingleRequestParameter=true,withSeparateModelsAndApi=true,modelPackage=models,apiPackage=api -o ./src/"
```

What worked for me is creating an axios instance, where I have defined my base url:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  response => {
    return response;
  },
  error => Promise.reject(error)
);

export default axiosInstance;
```

and then passing that to the actual request:

```
 const getUserData = async (id: string): Promise<UserDataDTO> => {
    const api = UserDataApiFp();
    const executeRequest = await api.apiUserDataIdGet(id);
    const response = await executeRequest(axiosInstance);
    return response.data;
  };
```